# How do I roleplay a journey?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, gm-techniques, campaign-development

I'm starting a new campaign and my players want to play a "journey". They want to explore a continent, walking to the objective, like a LOTR-styled thing. They literally want to walk through the forests and the mountains. How do I make such a thing? Is it possibile or is it too hard?